# append() to dynamically created tab

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am creating an editor application which requires dynamically appending HTML into the document. I am using JQuery UI tabs to divide the document into sections. I want to be able to dynamically add tabs and then use append() to add content into the tabs.

The page has 3 tabs when it loads and I want to be able to dynamically add more when required.

Currently my code works when appending content into the 3 non-dynamic tabs, and when creating a new tab. For some reason I cannot append any content into a new, dynamically created tab.

Why won't my code work for adding content to a dynamically created tab?

```
$(function () {
    $('#addTab').click(function () {
        var num_tabs = $('div#tabs ul li.tab').length + 1;
        $('div#tabs ul').append(
            '<li class="tab"><a href="#tab' + num_tabs + '">Section ' + num_tabs + '</a></li>');
        $('div#tabs').append(
            '<div id="tab-' + num_tabs + '></div>');
        $('#tabs').tabs("refresh");
        $('#tabs').tabs("option", "active", -1); //makes the new tab active
    });
});

//Insert content into the currently selected tab
function insertContent(content) {
    var activeTab = $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active');
    activeTab += 1;
    console.log(activeTab);
    $("#tab-" + activeTab).append(content);
}
```

HTML after creating a 4th tab:

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
 <li class="tab ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tab-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="false"><a href="#tab-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">Section 1</a></li>
 <li class="tab ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tab-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false"><a href="#tab-2" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">Section 2</a></li>
 <li class="tab ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tab-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="false"><a href="#tab-3" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3">Section 3</a></li>
 <li class="tab ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tab4" aria-labelledby="ui-id-7" aria-selected="true"><a href="#tab4" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-7">Section 4</a></li></ul>

 <div id="tab-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">Section Title:<input class="sectionTitle"><br><p contenteditable="true" class="cke_editable cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" tabindex="0" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-label="Rich Text Editor, editor1" title="Rich Text Editor, editor1" aria-describedby="cke_83" style="position: relative;">Paragraph text</p></div>

<div id="tab-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" style="display:none;">Section Title:<input class="sectionTitle"><p contenteditable="false" class="cke_editable cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" tabindex="0" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-label="Rich Text Editor, editor2" title="Rich Text Editor, editor2" aria-describedby="cke_153" style="position: relative;">Paragraph text</p></div>

<div id="tab-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">Section Title:<input class="sectionTitle"><p contenteditable="false" class="cke_editable cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" tabindex="0" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-label="Rich Text Editor, editor3" title="Rich Text Editor, editor3" aria-describedby="cke_223" style="position: relative;">Paragraph text</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the HTML generated following are the problems I found with your code:

1) The following line generated `li` with wrong Id i.e. `tab4` instead of `tab-4`

```
$('div#tabs ul').append(
            '<li class="tab"><a href="#tab' + num_tabs + '">Section ' + num_tabs + '</a></li>');
```

change `<a href="#tab'` to `<a href="#tab-'`

2) The following line was missing `"` in id because of which the div wasn't appended in the tabs

```
$('div#tabs').append(
            '<div id="tab-' + num_tabs + '"></div>');
```

Once you fix there, you'll see your code is working properly

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EKBqy/)

Comment: But this code works for the 3 existing tabs. I add 1 because the tab indexing starts from 0. Subtracting 1 wouldn't work

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. The code is working fine for the 3 existing tabs on the page. It is only when I add a 4th tab that the insertContent() function won't work. Nothing is appended to the tab. The activeTab variable has a value of 4 in this case, which is what I expect.

Comment: can you post the HTML that is generated once you have the 4th tab inserted?

Comment: Please see above. It seems that it is not actually adding the 4th tab, although it is adding a list item so the tab appears to be there. Any idea why?

Comment: Working, thank you so much. Is this a good way to dynamically add tabs? It seems very fiddly and prone to small syntax errors, and hard to debug. Is there a better way?

Comment: You are adding html as string to create element. As an alternative, you can add elements like `$('<div/>').attr('id', someId).appentTo('someDiv');`. This method is much better but not fool proof. BTW, feel free to mark this answer accepted if it helped you

Comment: how can I delete a tab ?